# How to specify the sheet name in Excel Export (NOT file name) - Ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid

When we export to excel in AgGrid, the default sheet name is ag-grid. How can I change it to another name?

Answer (score 3):

```
const params = {
  columnWidth: 100,
  fileName: 'Your File Name',
  sheetName:'Your Sheet Name'
};
this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel(params);
```

You can pass params inside `exportDataAsExcel()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the function `getDataAsExcel(params)` to generate the XML, then parse through it for the `Worksheet` element and change the `ss:Name` attribute to whatever you want for your sheet name. It *might* be safe to just use `str.replace` looking for `'ag-grid'`, but I am not certain on that.

Once that is done you just need to download the string/blob as a file.